# Session Some Time reurn Null And some time reurn value

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, webserver

I create session when user Login and use session to check access page, when i check session some time rerun null if i refresh page  or navigate to other page the session is not null , it's not about specific page ,it's about method some time return null some time get session value , my method in web service and i call it use javascript

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]            
    public object CheckIfLoggedin()
    {
        try
        {
            return new { Result = resultEnum.ok, Records = GetUserID() };

        }
        catch
        {
            return new { Result = resultEnum.error };
        }

    }
    private Guid? GetUserID()
    {
        if (Context.Session["User"] != null)
        {
            string userid = Context.Session["User"].ToString();
            if (userid != "")
                return new Guid(userid);
            else
                return null;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    function CheckIfLoggedin() {

var status = 0;

var ItemCount;
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "../../../../_layouts/15/TripPlannerFrontend/TripPlannerSrv.asmx/CheckIfLoggedin",

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (res) {
        if (res.d.Result === 2) {
            var userid = res.d.Records;
            if (userid == null) {
                //
            }
            else {

                //window.location = "TripPlanner.aspx";
                var returnurl = GetQueryString("returnurl");
                if (returnurl != null && returnurl !== "")
                    window.location = returnurl;
                else
                    window.location = "TripPlanner.aspx";
            } 

        }
        else
            console.log("try again");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log("try again");
    }
});
   };
```

Comment: check web.config about session expiration time ...it may be expiring ...

Comment: if session expire i will not be enable to read it if i refresh page it will be gone for ever but if i recall the method again i can read the session, i face a weird issue where the session gets null sometimes . this issue is not very consistent and sometimes session is null and sometimes not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is session affinity. If you have multiple Web front-ends   and a load-balancer dispatching requests to one of these SP servers: a first request may be routed to server A, then the session is created, and when a second request is issued by the client, it may be redirected to server B, where the session does not exist.

In such situations, the best approach is to configure your load-balancer for "session affinity": this means that once a given client is assigned one of the Web front-ends, all subsequent requests will be redirected to the same server. Please Ask the Administrator of the load-balancer if there is Session affinity configuration if not ask him  if this can be configured at his level (it depends on the technology used for load-balancing).